# TeamCity and Allure folders error while building

Tags: gradle, teamcity, allure

I constantly get an error on TeamCity caused by Allure folders.

If I run the build with:

```
gradlew clean test
```

I get the error:

> Execution failed for task ':clean'. org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete directory 'D:\BuildAgent\work{BUILD_NUMBER}\build'
> Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process has files open or has its working directory set in the target directory.- D:\BuildAgent\work{BUILD_NUMBER}\build\allure-results

and if I run the build with:

```
gradlew test
```

I get the error:

> Execution failed for task ':test'. org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not read path 'D:\BuildAgent\work{BUILD_NUMBER}\build\allure-results\history'.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Is your build agent checking files out of a source control defined by a vcsroot? Maybe ensure to do a clean checkout first before running the build?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the permission on the path? Also seeing issues on my side when running tests with gradle-wrapper. Do you use docker?